# Adding title to reference section of Pandoc HTML output

Tags: pandoc

I looked through the Pandoc HTML template and I wasn't able to find an option to include a header to the reference section when using `pandoc-citeproc`. Currently the output looks like the following:

```
<div class="references">
   <p>Some References</p>
</div>
```

How would it be possible to insert a `<h3>Reference</h3>` block directly above it? Neither the template nor the documentation mention a `$reference$` variable. This is the relevant section of the HTML template:

```
$body$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$
$endfor$
```

I would want to add something like this:

```
$body$
<h3>References</h3>
$references$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$
$endfor$
```

Answer (score 3):

As it says [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#citations), the way to do this is to end your document with a level-1 header with the name of the references section.  If you use `--number-sections` and don't want the references section numbered, you can include `{.unnumbered}` or just `{-}` after the title.